# How to calculate footer height which will be the difference between ListView.height and sum of height of visible elements

Tags: qt, qml

I have ListView where I want to aline elements by top of scroll area

[image]

I try do this throught add footer

[image]

And I try to calculate the footer height but get Error: 
qrc:/main.qml:28:17: QML Item: Binding loop detected for property "height"

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 50
        cacheBuffer:1000
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: dg
            property int yoff: Math.round(dg.y - list.contentY)
            property bool isFullyVisible: (yoff > list.y && yoff + height < list.y + list.height)
            border.color: Qt.darker(color, 1.2)
            color: isFullyVisible ? "#ccffcc" : "#fff"
            height: /*Math.random() **/ 100
            width: parent.width
            Text {text: "Fully visible: " + isFullyVisible + " dg.y: " + dg.y + " list.contentY: " +
                        list.contentY + " list.y: " + list.y + " list.height: " + list.height +
                        " dg.height: " + dg.height
                anchors.centerIn: parent}
        }

        footer: Item {
            id: ft

            function calculateFooterHeight(){

                var sumHeightOfVisibleElements = 0

                for(var child in list.contentItem.children) {
                    sumHeightOfVisibleElements += list.contentItem.children[child].height
                }

                    return sumHeightOfVisibleElements
            }

            width: parent.width
            height: list.height - calculateFooterHeight()
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to achieve, besides that the topic caption says? And please provide mvce, especially _minimal_, now you code is hard to read.

Comment: @folibis Sorry for my big code, but I don`t know how do it short. "besides that the topic caption says" a want to acheved result which is presented at picture. If I scroll the list to the end I want to aline to the top of scroll area instead of buttom.

Comment: @folibis and safe the emty space or fill it the footer which height depends of sum of content height

Comment: I guess you need `snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem; highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange`

Comment: @folibis Thank you. But It does not helped me. Only one item remains and the rest empty space is filled. But I need that the several items remains( how many whole elements fit in space ) and the rest of empty space is fiiled. Maybe i incorrect use this property.